# Sails_mysql adapter

Tags: mysql

I want to know how we can create more than one tables in MySQL using Node.js through ORM adapters. I have created a table through model i.e. 'us.js'

```
module.exports = {
    identity: 'us',

    connection: 'mysqlDB',
    schema:true,
    migrate: 'safe',

    attributes: {
        as_a: 'string',
        i_want_to: 'string',
        for_the:'string',
        so_that:'string'
    }
};
```

And built its connection as connections.js:

```
var mysqlAdapter = require('sails-mysql');
var mongoAdapter = require('sails-mongo');

module.exports = {
        adapters: {
            mongoAdapt: mongoAdapter,
            mysqlAdapt: mysqlAdapter
        },

      connections: {

        mysqlDB: {
            adapter: 'mysqlAdapt',
            host: 'localhost',
            database:'user_stories',
            user:'root',
            password:'',
            supportBigNumbers:true, //true/false
            debug:['ComQueryPacket'], //false or array of node-mysql debug
options
            trace:true //true/false
        }


      }
    };
```

So with the same connection how can I create more than one tables in MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new model for a new table. In the model, specify those attributes which you want as a fields in the table.

Comment: i have already done that but i dont know how to mention this new model in connection.js file???

Comment: You don't need to mention the model name in connection.js file for another model. You have to only update connection.js once for giving adapter name, username, password, db name etc. And model.js once for providing the adapter name. Your table for every model will be created automatically by sails.

Comment: Okay now i have gain understanding of how to do this thanx